# Spark Error: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope

Tags: apache-spark

I've created a spark standalone cluster on my laptop,
then I go into an sbt console on a spark project and try to embed a spark instance as so:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("foo").setMaster(/* Spark Master URL*/)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Up to there everything works fine, then I try

```
sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3))
// and I get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are your Spark versions compatible?

Comment: Yes they are both 1.4.1

Comment: How did you solve the above issue ? I am having the same issue with 1.4.1

Comment: By any chance are you including extra jackson libraries (other than ones included in your Spark install) in your runtime classpath (either in build.sbt or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 7):

maybe you missed following `lib`.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

this error message is usually accompanied by 
`Cause: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.8`

it means there are conflict versions in the dependencies (obviously). in the Spark world, usually it is because some lib we use has dependency conflict with spark shipped one.

use [coursier resolve](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-resolve) can find out what's happening. (gradle also has [debugging dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html).

```
cs resolve org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.5 | grep jackson
cs resolve com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-json4s_2.11:0.10.0 | grep jackson
```

then either build a [uber jar](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#bundling-your-applications-dependencies) for our application, or excluding the conflict in the build (if it is possible). e.g. `build.gradle`

```
    testCompile 'com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-json4s_%%:0.10.0', { exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core' }
```

Comment: how did you know the conflict was with scalapb-json4s?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following jar to the Bin folder of the spark if you using spark console.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9.3